# Prove that $n$ is even and $|A| \in \{-1,1 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $A \in M_{n} (\mathbb R)$, such that $A^2=-I_{n}$. Prove that $n$ is even and $|A| \in \{-1,1 \}$.

I started by compute the determinant of both sides:

$A^2=-I_{n}\Leftrightarrow$

$|A^2|=|-I_{n}|\Leftrightarrow$

$|A|\cdot |A|=(-1)^n|I_{n}|\Leftrightarrow$

$|A|\cdot |A|=(-1)^n$

It's known that $|A|$ is a real number. The product of two equal real numbers is always positive. So $n$ must be even. I can write:

$|A|\cdot |A|=1$

To get the previous result there are two possibilities, $|A|=1$ or $|A|=-1$. My doubt is if there is more posibilities. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution looks good.

Comment: Yes. Your proof is valid

Comment: Just one remark: the product of two equal real numbers is always **non-negative**

Comment: @user127001 Are you sure ^^ ?

Comment: @user127001 I added the word "equal", but you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no more possibilities. Maybe it's a bit more obvious if you write it:

$$|A| \cdot |A| = |A|^2 = 1.$$

The proof is fine, up to "The product of two equal real numbers is always $\color{darkred}{\text{positive}}$" (should be "nonnegative", as [user127001](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/50800/user127001) wrote in the comments), but this really changes nothing, since your product is nonzero.